# App Service WordPress Storage Account Not Working

Tags: wordpress, azure-web-app-service

I setup a new WordPress site on Azure App Service using the Quick Start guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-wordpress

During the setup I chose to have content saved to Azure Storage, however this is not working.
As per https://github.com/Azure/wordpress-linux-appservice/blob/main/WordPress/wordpress_azure_blob_storage.md the following Application Settings are correct:

BLOB_STORAGE_ENABLED - true
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME - valid name
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY - valid key
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME - valid name

They were created during the setup and haven't been changed.

When I upload an image, it does not appear in storage but on the App Service file system.  I can see the files using SCM site.

Is there another setting or a way to determine the issue?

Comment: `When I upload an image, it does not appear in storage but on the App Service file system. I can see the files using SCM site`.How you are uploading images ?

Comment: I'm using the standard Media > Add New

Comment: Iam able to see the uploaded file in Blob Storage as well.[StorageAccount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSEc5.png) and [Azure AppService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvGFk.png)

Comment: Are you sure, have you enabled Storage Account option while creating the Wordpress App.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd6o0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> App Service WordPress Storage Account Not Working

I have followed the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-wordpress#create-wordpress-site-using-azure-portal) which you have provided and able to upload the images and see them in Blob Storage.

[image]

> BLOB_STORAGE_ENABLED - true STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME - valid name STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY - valid key BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME - valid name

Even I have the same configuration in the Configuration section.

[image]

In `Storage Account` =>under `Data Storage` select  `Containers`

Images are getting uploaded in the `wpbloba48da09bd8\wp-content\uploads\2023\07\` folder.

[image]

***App Service:***
[image]